# Tidy Verse Issue

Tags: r, filter, pipe, tidyverse

I am using tidyverse for the first time and I am very new to R and Rstudio.

I installed the tidyverse package in Rstudio and continued with my code. 
My code until now is just this:

```
library (tidyverse)
damsel <- read.csv("mecistogaster_in_bromeliads_multiyear.csv")
damsel %>% filter (genus == "Weruhaia")
```

1. When I piped, it gave me the error saying that object 'genus' is not found.
2. When I looked into my packages tidyverse was not ticked-- So I tried to again reload it by typing library (tidyverse).

It showed me the following error 'Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘pillar’'

I have tried to restart R three times since this issue and all the three times I get the same error.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: It's too little information to answer. You did not show what you happen(example or error code). I don't know where the problem is in code or what the problem is in code. Isn't it? It may not true you guessed.

Comment: @Sangwonkim: Does it make sense now?

Comment: @mikeck: Alright I shall try that. but the error which I am facing is mainly with loading tidyverse I guess. and I have added the error message now...

Comment: Usually dplyr is included in the tidyverse. However, in the case of you, you must install dplyr because it is not in the namespace. Did it work?

Comment: @Sangwonkim: No... It still gives me tje same error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run

`Install.packages(“tidyverse”)`

cderv wrote on community.studio.com:

`install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = TRUE)` to install everything tidyverse depends on.

Once installed.

`library(tidyverse)`

This may be the blind leading the blind, but...  Have you successfully installed any packages?  If not, there could be an issue of where your packages are installing.

Comment: I used the option provided on the right side box with the install icon next to it..... ? and I have the same issue if I use dplyr too. The error which I am getting is "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘pillar’

Comment: If you are seeing tidyverse in the list of packages, but it isnt checked, it should be installed, but not loaded.   Run library(tidyverse) again.    Load the library first then try running your code separately.

Comment: I did try loading it thrice... but I keep ending up with the same error.... where do packages need to be installed?

Comment: I keep getting the same error ' Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘pillar’ and I am unable to load any packages such as dplyr or tidyverse...